# Swap populated 2D arrays

Tags: vba

I have 3 arrays (named Array1, Array2, Array3 ) stored inside a variant which are populated with values. What is the simplest approach that upon pressing a button, will allow me to swap Array1 values (still maintaining row & column order) with those of Array3 and vice versa? Array 2 remains untouched.

Comment: [Search for swap array in VBA](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=swap+arrays+vba&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: Hi Dee, I have done so but it typically refers to swapping elements inside a single array which I have already written. I'm not saying there isn't any results but I didn't find anything. I'm not looking for code, just simple theory. I've considered creating a temporary array to copy items from Array1, then copy the items from Array3 to Array1, finally copy items from temporary array to array 3. That might be the simplest solution but I just want to see if anyone has an alternative that might be simpler which I haven't considered.

Comment: "upon pressing a button" is entirely irrelevant to the question. If you have code that doesn't do what it was written to do, then *post it* and tell us about what it's doing vs what it *should* be doing. See [mcve].

Comment: I haven't written code for this task yet, I decided to post here prior to doing so to determine if any suggestions offered by others would be simpler than the approach I have suggested. If I had code that wasn't doing what I wanted, I would have posted it. Once again I am not looking for someone to provide code, just discuss suggestions of methods how to approach this or provide actual valid links to that shows how others have achieved it instead of a google link which doesn't even contain a valid result to my question on the first page or results.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, swapping in general is done with help of some temp storage where the content is held temporarily between swaps.

Comment: Thank you Dee, that's all I was looking for. For some reason I thought I would have to loop through all rows and columns in each array during the copy process hence why I posted a simple question to see if there was a better method. I discovered I don't have to do that and have posted the solution I now use below.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out my initial theory is likely the simplest way after all and achieves what I was looking to do in 3 lines of code.

```
TempArray = ArraysSorted(0)
ArraysSorted(0) = ArraysSorted(2)
ArraysSorted(2) = TempArray
```

Locals window confirms that the all items remain in their initial row/column position only within a different array.